# Mockito method call stub not working - Mockito.doReturn(false).when(studentServiceImpl).myClass().isValidUser(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

adding test cases for getStudent method, this is having internal calls

1- is repository call - stubbing  this call working fine

2- validate user call - stubbing this call not working, showing some error and test case failed.

***Service Class***

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    FakeStudentRepository fakeStudentRepository;
    @Override
    public Optional<Student> getStudent(int id) {
        Optional<Student> student = fakeStudentRepository.getStudent(id);
        boolean isValid = myClass().isValidUser(student.get().getId());
        if(!isValid) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return student;
    }
    public MyTestClass myClass() {
        return new MyTestClass();
    }
 }
```

***MyTestClass***

```
public class MyTestClass {
    public boolean isValidUser(int id) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@SpringBootTest
class StudentServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    FakeStudentRepository fakeStudentRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    StudentServiceImpl studentServiceImpl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        studentServiceImpl = Mockito.spy(StudentServiceImpl.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void getStudent() {
        Optional<Student> student = Optional.of(Student.builder().id(1).firstName("Rahul").lastName("rahul")
                .mobile("XXXXXX").build());

        Mockito.doReturn(student)
                .when(fakeStudentRepository).getStudent(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());

        Mockito.doReturn(false)
                .when(studentServiceImpl).myClass().isValidUser(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());

        Optional<Student> resultStudent = studentServiceImpl.getStudent(student.get().getId());
        assertEquals(resultStudent.get().getId(), student.get().getId());
    }
}
```

**Error**

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:  Boolean
>   cannot be returned by myClass() myClass() should return MyTestClass
>
> If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. Due to the
>   nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>   1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.    Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency
>   testing.
>   2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
>      - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error Message says it: You are mocking `studentServiceImpl.myClass()` and try to return true. It’s not possible to mock the end of a call chain as you try with your second Mockito expression.

To do what you want requires to mock `myClass()` first by returning a mocked class instance and mock `isValidUser` on that.